# What does the "Nullable context" actually do?

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I've seen the documentation for C#'s [nullable contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) but there is something I don't understand:

Does enabling the nullable context for any piece of code JUST makes it start showing warnings when null may be assigned to a "shouldn't be null" type?

I was under the impression it would tell the compiler "I promise this won't be null, so shut up about it." but it seems it does the opposite? "Let me know when something can be null, because I'm paranoid."?

Is that it?

Comment: The docs seem pretty clear about this. `#nullable` just allows you to opt in to the new behavior. It doesn't do anything itself to mark things as (not) nullable beyond reference types then defaulting to being not nullable (so you can use `?` to mark them as nullable). Annotations take care of the rest. When the nullable context is disabled, the compiler won't give any warnings about things possibly being `null` at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, if the docs were clear about it I wouldn't be asking. And, honestly, it seems to me you did not understand or read my question, as your comment is in the general area but missing my point. Does the context JUST enable warnings or not?

Comment: `#nullable warnings` JUST enables warnings. `#nullable enable` enables warnings as well as nullable annotations to make those warnings go away. As this is literally what the docs say I'll accept that I'm not getting your point. Perhaps it helps if you think of `#nullable` as turning on the features that *allow* for nullability checking and having nothing to do with telling the compiler (*on its own*) about what things can be `null`. In particular, turning on NRTs does not go into some sort of "provably not `null` mode" where exceptions are impossible; the designers though that too ambitious.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yes, I think in the end we understood each-other, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft introduced "*nullable aware context*" in C# 8.

"*In a nullable aware context:*

- *A variable of a reference type T must be initialized with non-null,
  and may never be assigned a value that may be null.*
- *A variable of a reference type T? may be initialized with null or
  assigned null, but is required to be checked against null before
  de-referencing.*
- *A variable m of type T? is considered to be non-null when you apply
  the null-forgiving operator, as in m!.*

*The distinctions between a non-nullable reference type T and a nullable reference type T? are enforced by the compiler's interpretation of the preceding rules. A variable of type T and a variable of type T? are represented by the same .NET type.*"

[Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types)

If the *nullable aware context* is enabled and no value is assigned when a variable is declared, the following warnings may be given:

*"CS8618 - Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable."* src: [CS8618- Nonnullable reference not initialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8618)#nonnullable-reference-not-initialized)

*"CS8600 - Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type."* src: [CS8600 - Possible null assigned to a nonnullable reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8600)#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference)

Examples of correctly declared variables:

```
string notNull = "Hello";
string? nullable = default;
notNull = nullable!; // null forgiveness
StreamWriter? streamWriter = null;
```

This feature can be turned on and off using the `<nullable>enable</nullable` or disable attribute in the Project file. Since the feature is disable by default in .NET 6, the attribute can also be removed to disable it.

[Nullable contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Additional information:

[Learn techniques to resolve nullable warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-warnings)

[Update a codebase with nullable reference types to improve null diagnostic warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies)